# Django выражение F(поле)

Tags: django

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(some_field=F('id') * 2)
```

Здесь id - это id самой модели SomeModel.
Предположим, что вместо id я хочу получить forein.id, где forein - это поле foreinkey модели SomeModel. То есть мне нужно нечто вроде:
SomeModel.objects.filter(some_field=F('forein_id') * 2)
Как получить такой запрос? Может быть вместо F() надо нечто другое использовать?